# sub query in SQL server with multi values

Tags: c#, sql-server

how to insert into table a 3 columns from a sub query where this sub query return values from two outer join tables ....in common please

```
Select pay_std_Id,Course.Course_id,Pay_Term_Id 
from  course 
inner join Payment_Course_Detail
On Course.Course_id = Payment_Course_Detail.Course_Id
inner join Payment
On Payment.Pay_Id = Payment_Course_Detail.Pay_Id
where Pay_Std_ID in (select Pay_Std_ID = @payId)
```

Comment: Please format code as code for readabilty reasons. Does the target table already exist? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: when i need to insert these values to a table appears this error  Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Please show your complete code. How does the INSERT look like?

Comment: insert into Studies_Profile (Std_Id,Course_id,Term_Id)
 select Pay_Std_ID,Course.Course_Id,Pay_Term_Id from Payment,Course where @payId in(
Select  pay_std_Id,Course.Course_id,Pay_Term_Id from  course inner join 
Payment_Course_Detail
On Course.Course_id = Payment_Course_Detail.Course_Id
inner join Payment
On Payment.Pay_Id = Payment_Course_Detail.Pay_Id
where Pay_Std_ID in (select Pay_Std_ID = @payId))

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible:

```
where @payId in (Select pay_std_Id, Course.Course_id, Pay_Term_Id
```

because the subquery returns three columns instead of one!

Comment: Just return one column instead of three, the column you want to compare @payId with. But the whole subquery looks strange to me.